# i would ilke to select all sub strings from given string by regex javascript start with 'CREATE TABLE' and end with ';'

Tags: regex

i would ilke to select all substrings from 'CREATE TABLE' to ';' in below string. In this string there should be 2 matches.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `u3g8_student` (
  `student_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `roll_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1087 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

1.this line should not be matched

```sql
CREATE TABLE `u3g8_student` (
  `student_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `roll_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1087 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

https://regex101.com/r/DWWkzy/4

Tried this

```
CREATE.*;$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this would likely work on `gs` mode:

```
\bCREATE\b[^;]*;
```

if we wouldn't have nested queries with `;` or other additional `;`s.

#### Test

```js
const regex = /\bCREATE\b[^;]*;/sg;
const str = `i would ilke to select all substrings from 'CREATE TABLE' to ';' in below string. In this string there should be 2 matches.

CREATE TABLE \`u3g8_student\` (
  \`student_id\` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  \`roll_number\` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  \`
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1087 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

1.this line should not be matched


CREATE TABLE \`u3g8_student\` (
  \`student_id\` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  \`roll_number\` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  \`
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1087 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZjaEdI/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ZjaEdI/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]